# DataGridView does not show DataTable when selection mode is FullColumnSelect

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datasource

How can I bind to a DataSource (DataTable) when the selection mode of my DataGridView is set to FullColumnSelect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if theres a proper way to do it, or if this is it, but i got mine to work like so;

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGrid.Columns)
        {
            col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
            col.Selected = false;
        }
        dataGrid.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect;
```

So for each column in the datagrid, you set the sortmode to notsortable (this may be the only way), and selected to false. Then change the selection mode to fullcolumn select, and the first column to selected = true.

You can probably have the last line of code in the designer mode if you wanted, i.e. change it when you click on the datagrid in design mode.

Comment: When do you do it, before or after setting the datasource? Before, there are no columns yet (my data source is always different), and after it is to late, because InvalidOperationException is triggered.

Comment: sorry, was my error. Of course, after setting columns are already available. It works, thank you!

Comment: no worries : ) i set the datasource before looping through the columns.